# Using regex groups in dplyr

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a string:

```
txt <- "Harris P R, Harris D L (1983). Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture. Journal of European Industrial Training, 7(7): 22."
```

I want to extract author name(s), year, and title from this string. This command, based on `regex101` works:

```
result <- regmatches(txt, regexec("([^\\(]+) \\((\\d+)\\). ([^\\.]+).", txt))

result[[1]][2]
[1] "Harris P R, Harris D L"

result[[1]][3]
[1] "1983"

result[[1]][4]
[1] "Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture"
```

Assume I have a data frame of strings like txt, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(txt = c("Harris P R, Harris D L (1983). Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture. Journal of European Industrial Training, 7(7): 22.",
"Cruise M J, Gorenberg B D (1985). The tools of management: keeping high touch in a high tech world. International nursing review, 32(6): 166-169, 173."))
```

I would like to use regex groups in `dplyr` as follows:

```
new_df <- df %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = "row_id") %>%
    mutate(result = regmatches(txt, regexec("([^\\(]+) \\((\\d+)\\). ([^\\.]+).", txt)),
           authors = result[[row_id]][2],
           year = result[[row_id]][3],
           title = result[[row_id]][4])
```

This does not work.

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `authors = result[[row_id]][2]`.
Caused by error in `result[[row_id]]`:
! no such index at level 1
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

rlang::last_error()

<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `authors = result[[row_id]][2]`.
Caused by error in `result[[row_id]]`:
! no such index at level 1
---
Backtrace:
 1. df %>% rownames_to_column(var = "row_id") %>% ...
 3. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 4. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
 6. mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

What changes do I need to make? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strcapture` in the mutate call with that regex:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    strcapture("([^\\(]+) \\((\\d+)\\). ([^\\.]+).", txt, 
               list(authors="", year=0L, title=""))
  ) %>%
  select(-txt)
#                     authors year                                                            title
# 1    Harris P R, Harris D L 1983                     Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture
# 2 Cruise M J, Gorenberg B D 1985 The tools of management: keeping high touch in a high tech world
```

(I'm inferring `year` should be an integer.)

*Edit*: I'm getting rid of your code and sticking with the `strcapture`.

Loading your [`publications.csv`](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/opcEhmRXrJYyKBZ), we can look at the failures (nothing *breaks*). I'll include row 1 which is "good" so that we have a fair reference:

```r
pubs <- read.csv("publications.csv") # 217 rows
pubs %>%
  mutate(
    strcapture("([^\\(]+) \\((\\d+)\\). ([^\\.]+).", Reference, 
               list(authors="", year=0L, title=""))
  ) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1 | !complete.cases(.))
#                                                                                                                                                                                                      Reference    authors year                                                  title
# 1                                                                                            Naisbitt J (1982). Megatrends : ten new directions transforming our lives. New York, United States: Warner Books. Naisbitt J 1982 Megatrends : ten new directions transforming our lives
# 2                                                                                                              Spitzer, D.R. 1987. "Megatrends" in Educational Technology. Educational Technology 27(9):44-47.       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 3                                   Binning, P.J., M.B. Hauger, M. Rygaard, A.M. Eilersen, and H.J. Albrechtsen. 2006. Rethinking the urban water management of Copenhagen. Water Practice and Technology 1(2)       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 4                                                                                                                    Smith S T (2008) Megatrends in higher education. Ed.D. thesis, University of North Texas.       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 5                                                                                         Laval V (2015) Impact of Recent Megatrends on the Controlling Role Model. Procedia Economics and Finance, 27: 54-63.       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 6                                                    Aden N T (2017) Manufacturing a Stable Climate: Drivers of Industrial Sector Greenhouse Gas Mitigation. Ph.D. thesis, University of California, Berkeley.       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 7  McCracken, M., L.E.R. Peters, and A.T. Wolf, Chapter 7. Megatrends in Shared Waters in 2030 and Beyond, in Assessing Global Water Megatrends, Water Resources Development and Management. 2018. p. 105-123.       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 8                                                       Wong, S.Y. and B.H. Tan. 2019. Megatrends in Infectious Diseases: The Next 10 to 15 Years. Annals of the Academy of Medicine, Singapore 48(6):188-194.       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 9                                                                              Mara_, V., M. Bugarinovi_, E. Anoyrkati, and A. Avarello. 2019. Megatrends, a way to identify the future transport challenges.        <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
# 10                                                                                              van Dorsser, C. and P. Taneja. 2020. An Integrated Three-Layered Foresight Framework. Foresight 22(2):250-272.       <NA>   NA                                                   <NA>
```

Note that the year is not in parentheses, as you assumed. We can add some conditioning to your regex (i.e., adding `?` for `\\(?(\\d+)\\)?`), and then do some weak validation by checking that all `year` are between 1900 and 2100:

```r
pubs %>%
  mutate(
    strcapture("([^\\(]+) \\(?(\\d+)\\)?. ([^\\.]+).", Reference, 
               list(authors="", year=0L, title=""))
  ) %>% 
  filter(!between(year, 1900, 2100))
#                                                                                                                                                Reference                                                                          authors year title
# 1 Wong, S.Y. and B.H. Tan. 2019. Megatrends in Infectious Diseases: The Next 10 to 15 Years. Annals of the Academy of Medicine, Singapore 48(6):188-194. Wong, S.Y. and B.H. Tan. 2019. Megatrends in Infectious Diseases: The Next 10 to    1 Years
```

Okay, last step, it appears the `.` after `Tan` is causing a problem here. Let's strengthen the regex even more by forcing the year component to be 4 characters. This fixed that issue, but we have one more, I'll highlight it by looking for a four-digit number in the `authors` field:

```r
pubs %>%
  mutate(
    strcapture("([^\\(]+) \\(?(\\d+{4})\\)?. ([^\\.]+).", Reference, 
               list(authors="", year=0L, title=""))
  ) %>% 
  filter(grepl("\\d{4}", authors))
#                                                                                                                                                                                                     Reference                                                                                                                                                                                   authors year title
# 1 McCracken, M., L.E.R. Peters, and A.T. Wolf, Chapter 7. Megatrends in Shared Waters in 2030 and Beyond, in Assessing Global Water Megatrends, Water Resources Development and Management. 2018. p. 105-123. McCracken, M., L.E.R. Peters, and A.T. Wolf, Chapter 7. Megatrends in Shared Waters in 2030 and Beyond, in Assessing Global Water Megatrends, Water Resources Development and Management. 2018     p
```

This is going to be a problem: *there is no year* anywhere near the authors' names. This one appears to have been broken somewhere on data creation, perhaps the source itself has spoiled data. Either way, I don't know if/how to remedy this one easily in regex, I suggest you patch *this one entry* by editing your CSV and fixing it manually. That will be much better (imo) than trying to fix this programmatically. (I'm open to robust solutions that don't require significant effort in regex.)

Comment: The solution works well for the toy example provided. I have a data frame of 217 references. The `mutate` step breaks when the regex encounters a problem reference. I may end up having to loop through each row and use error trapping to deal with this.

Comment: Which mutate, using `strcapture` or `regexec`? Does the `mutate` "break" (error), or does it return `NA`? If the latter, then either the regex needs to be more resilient (optional groups?), or you need to catch this before `select(-txt)` so that you can attempt something else.

Comment: Both. `mutate` breaks.

Comment: How? With what data? I can only help if I can see and better reproduce the error. (Try with various subsets of rows until you find "the row(s)" that break it. I don't need all 217 rows :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. You can access the file here: https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/opcEhmRXrJYyKBZ

Comment: See my edits. Your presumption that the regex worked was incomplete. For clarity, *"both mutate breaks"* misrepresented the situation: the `regexec` broke (produced an error) for a couple of reasons; the `strcapture` just didn't see the data because the regex was incomplete, but it never erred, it executed exactly as the regex commanded.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `unnest`ing could be useful here:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(result = regmatches(txt, regexec("([^\\(]+) \\((\\d+)\\). ([^\\.]+).", txt))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(result) %>% 
  select(authors = ...2, year = ...3, title = ...4)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  authors                   year  title                                                         
  <chr>                     <chr> <chr>                                                         
1 Harris P R, Harris D L    1983  Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture                  
2 Cruise M J, Gorenberg B D 1985  The tools of management: keeping high touch in a high tech wo…
```